# Writing a batch file to copy network file and open it then close and loop

Tags: batch

We have a file on the network that is regularly updated and I need it open and up to date, but when its open no one else can access it to update it for me.

so I thought I might have a script that will:

- copy the file to my desktop
- open the file and wait an hour
- close winword (only that instance not all)
- delete the file
- go back to start.

I cannot find a way to only close the file rather than every winword.

Here is the sript so far (edited out anything private)

```
echo off
cls
echo.
TIMEOUT /T 10 /NOBREAK
echo.

:start

echo.
echo Updating File...
echo.

copy "T:\Shared\file.doc" "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop"

echo.
echo.

TIMEOUT /T 2

echo.
echo Opening File
echo.

start "File" "file.doc"

echo.
echo Waiting For One Hour... 
echo.

TIMEOUT /T 3600

echo.
echo Deleting Old File
echo.

del "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\file.doc"

goto start
```

Comment: You might try [@Kill](http://www.aswit.com/akill/), which supposedly can kill based on window names (`akill -K "file.doc"`).  `taskkill` can find window names, but as you probably are aware, it kills every Word window.

Comment: Good question.  I must have mistyped something when I tried it previously because it closed every Word window I had open.  I tried it again and it closed only the specific document.

I'm curious, though, since the answer is so easy, why is your answer so complicated?  The OP re-uses a document title, so closing only that document is simple.

Comment: @benJephunneh I'm not sure what you mean by my answer being complicated it's just a basic batch script & you set the variables in it accordingly but I deleted my comment since you saw it already. I was just pointing out to you that TASKKILL has a built-in feature for this method & there's no need to use third party software for this since it's already built into windows to kill a task based on it's title metadata. If that machine has another session and someone has a document opened with that same title, then closing it based on the title metadata will close all those;The PID is what he needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the **PID** of the process to call or the file to open with [WMIC](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) and set the **process ID** number to a variable, and then later use that variable with [TASKKILL](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) using the `/PID` switch which I posted the example batch script below and then another below that based on your logic how I think this needs to fit into it but adjust accordingly as needed.

This logic creates a couple dynamic temp files, using a [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to parse the process ID which is piped to the temp file to capture just the numerical value that'll be used with [TASKKILL](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) to kill that specific process ID (i.e.`/PID` switch).

This logic does the following:

1. **Opens the process\file**
2. **Waits an hour**
3. **Closes only that instance of the process\opened file**

---

---

**Batch Script Example**

***(Start a process, capture the [PID] Process ID of that process, and then later kill that process based on the same Process ID)***

*This script sets the application variable and might need to be the full path to the app on the machine (**`SET App=`**), and the full path to the file which that app will open, etc. (**`SET AppFile=`**).*

```
@ECHO ON

:::SET App=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\WINWORD.EXE
SET App=%windir%\%Notepad.exe
:::SET AppFile=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ENTER_EXIT_List.docx
SET AppFile=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\List.txt

SET DynamicTempFile1=%temp%\~tmpProcessID1_%~nx0.dat
SET DynamicTempFile2=%temp%\~tmpProcessID2_%~nx0.dat
IF EXIST "%DynamicTempFile1%" DEL /Q /F "%DynamicTempFile1%"
IF EXIST "%DynamicTempFile2%" DEL /Q /F "%DynamicTempFile2%"

::start a process and pass it a file, etc. to open or process and then pipe the process ID to a temp file
WMIC PROCESS CALL CREATE "%App% %AppFile%" | FIND "ProcessId">>"%DynamicTempFile1%"

::parse out unneeded characters for only numeric values from temp file
FOR /F "DELIMS==; TOKENS=2" %%F IN (%DynamicTempFile1%) DO ECHO %%~F >> "%DynamicTempFile2%"

::sets the PID to a variable with the value in the temp file
SET /P processid= < %DynamicTempFile2%

::wait 3600 seconds or one hour and then run the taskkill command
PING /n 3600 127.0.0.1 > nul

::kill process by PID from the previously set variable
TASKKILL /PID %processid%

GOTO EOF
```

### Further Resources

- [**WMIC**](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)
- [**TASKKILL**](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)
- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

---

---

**Script example based on your logic**

*This assumes you are opening up and killing the file which is copied but just set the variable up top.*

```
ECHO OFF

::://Set application full path and the app file full path that the app will open
:::SET App=%windir%\%Notepad.exe
:::SET AppFile=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\List.txt

SET App=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\WINWORD.EXE
SET DesktopFolder=C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop
::SET AppFile=%DesktopFolder%\file.doc
SET AppFile=C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop\file.doc
SET CopyFile=T:\Shared\file.doc

SET DynamicTempFile1=%temp%\~tmpProcessID1_%~nx0.dat
SET DynamicTempFile2=%temp%\~tmpProcessID2_%~nx0.dat
IF EXIST "%DynamicTempFile1%" DEL /Q /F "%DynamicTempFile1%"
IF EXIST "%DynamicTempFile2%" DEL /Q /F "%DynamicTempFile2%"

CLS
ECHO.
TIMEOUT /T 10 /NOBREAK
ECHO.

:start

ECHO.
ECHO Updating File...
ECHO.

COPY /Y "%CopyFile%" "%DesktopFolder%"

ECHO.
ECHO.

TIMEOUT /T 2

ECHO.
ECHO Opening File
ECHO.

:::START "File" "file.doc"
::start a process and pass it a file, etc. to open or process and then pipe the process ID to a temp file
WMIC PROCESS CALL CREATE "%App% %AppFile%" | FIND "ProcessId">>"%DynamicTempFile1%"

::parse out unneeded characters for only numeric values from temp file
FOR /F "DELIMS==; TOKENS=2" %%F IN (%DynamicTempFile1%) DO ECHO %%~F >> "%DynamicTempFile2%"

::sets the PID to a variable with the value in the temp file
SET /P processid= < %DynamicTempFile2%

ECHO.
ECHO Waiting For One Hour... 
ECHO.

TIMEOUT /T 3600

ECHO.
ECHO Deleting Old File
ECHO.

::kill process by PID from the previously set variable
TASKKILL /PID %processid%

DEL /Q /F "%AppFile%"

GOTO start
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea I have is to open the file in WordPad and then just use task kill on that which won't disturb open word docs!

Edit didn't work, opened up gibberish.

Edit 2:. Used wordviewer.exe and my idea work.

I now use task kill on wordviewer and that leaves my other word docs alone!

Then it's loops every hour to a fresh copy of the file!